# Chart.js Stacked Bar Chart with Groups

Tags: jquery-ui, chart

I have used Chart.js to draw a Stacked Bar Chart with Groups.

I want customization in it.

I want to show one bar as a completed bar and another one as Not Completed bar

As shown in the below.

Blue, Red, Yellow are the different applications. The bar shows no of task completed and not completed count against each application.

[image]

Questions

1) How can I wrap the text Not Completed as it is overlapping on another bar ?

2) On hover the the tooptip also overlaps on another bar please find the below image for the ref
[image]

Code written by me is as below

```
    <!doctype html>
```

Stacked Bar Chart with Groups

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../utils.js"></script>
<style>
canvas {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Member Agreement Tracker',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [
                66,
                93,
                31,
                76,
                39,
                75,
                36
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Employee On Boarding',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [
                76,
                203,
                41,
                86,
                49,
                85,
                46
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Vendor Payment',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
            stack: 'Stack 0',
            data: [
                76,
                103,
                41,
                86,
                49,
                85,
                46
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Employee On Boarding',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            stack: 'Stack 1',
            data: [
                56,
                56,
                83,
                21,
                66,
                29,
                65
            ]
        }]

    };
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Wisdom Application My To Do'
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true,
                    custom: function (tooltipModel) {

                    }
                },
                animation: {
                  duration: 1000,
                  currentStep:1,
                  onComplete: function() {
                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                    ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                    var stackGroup = [];
                    var stackIndex = [];
                    for (index = 0; index < this.data.datasets.length; index++) {
                        var stackName = this.data.datasets[index].stack;
                        var stack = { Name : stackName, stackIndex : index}
                        var result = stackGroup.filter(obj => {
                          return obj.Name === stackName
                        });
                        if(result.length>0){
                            var sliceCount = stackGroup.findIndex(x => x.Name==stackName);
                            stackGroup.splice(sliceCount, true);
                            stackIndex.splice(sliceCount, true);
                            stackGroup.push(stack);
                            stackIndex.push(stack.stackIndex);
                        }
                        else{
                            stackGroup.push(stack);
                            stackIndex.push(stack.stackIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                      var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                      meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                        var result = stackGroup.filter(obj => {
                          return obj.stackIndex === i
                        });
                        if(result.length>0){
                            if(result[0].Name=="Stack 0"){
                                ctx.fillText("Completed", bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                            }
                            if(result[0].Name=="Stack 1"){
                                var str = "Not<br/>Completed";
                                var html = $.parseHTML(str);
                                ctx.fillText("NotCompleted", bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                            }
                        }
                        //if($.inArray(i, stackIndex) !== -1){
                            //ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                        //}
                      });
                    });
                  }
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                         scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Task Count'
                          }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };

    document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
        barChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                return randomScalingFactor();
            });
        });
        window.myBar.update();
    });
</script>
```